# Technical question about random walks

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

(My original question still has not been answered. I have added further clarifications.)

When analyzing random walks (on undirected graphs) by viewing the random walk as a Markov chain, we require the graph to be non-bipartite so that the fundamental theorem of Markov chains applies.

What happens if the graph $G$ is instead bipartite? I am specifically interested in the hitting time $h_{i,j}$, where there is an edge between $i$ and $j$ in $G$. Say the bipartite graph $G$ has $m$ edges. We can add a self-loop to an arbitrary vertex in the graph to make the resulting graph $G'$ non-bipartite; applying the fundamental theorem of Markov chains to $G'$ we then get that $h_{i,j} < 2m+1$ in $G'$, and this is clearly also an upper bound for $h_{i,j}$ in $G$.

Question: Is it true that the stronger claim $h_{i,j} < 2m$ holds in $G$? (It have seen this claimed in analyses of the random walk algorithm for 2SAT.) Or do we really have to go through this extra step of adding the self-loop?

Answer (score 5):

**This answer proved something different from what the questioner was actually interested in. Leaving it here so others won't repeat the same mistake.**

> In most cases, one can formally justify the intuitive notion that
>   "self loops can only slow down the walk" by a coupling argument.  In
>   this case for example, one can couple the walk with the self loops
>   (let's call it $A$) and the one without the self loops (let's call
>   that $B$) so that $A$ takes the *same* steps as $B$, but delayed in
>   time.  This can for example be done as follows:  Suppose that $B$
>   starts at $u = x_0$ and goes through $x_i: i =1,2,\ldots,k$. Now, we
>   implement $A$ as follows: $A$ also goes through the same vertices as
>   $B$, except that vertex $x_i$, it waits for Geometric($p_i$) time
>   where $p_i$ is the self loop probability at $x_i$.  Note that this is
>   a correct implementation of $A$ (all transition probabilities are
>   correct), and the form of the coupling ensures that $A$ never reaches
>   any vertex before $B$, that is, we have coupled $H_t^A$ and $H_t^B$
>   (the random hitting times in the two walks) so that $H_t^A \geq H_t^B$
>   with probability $1$. Thus, the inequality for the expected hitting
>   time follows.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this answers my question. I agree that $h_{i,j}$ in $G$ is upper bounded by $h_{i,j}$ in $G'$, which is in turn upper bounded by $2m+1$. But I would like to obtain the stronger bound that $h_{i,j}$ in $G$ is upper bounded by $2m$. (OK, I realize that the "$+1$" is not a big deal, but on the other hand I have seen the claim made without the "$+1$" and so I wonder whether it is technically accurate.)

Comment: @user686 Can you share the reference?

Answer (score 2):

I had posted this as a comment before, and I believe it answers user686's  modified question in the affirmative (when $i$ and $j$ are connected by an edge in a graph $G$ (no matter whether it is bipartite or not), $h(i,j)$, the expected hitting time from $i$ to $j$ satisfies $h(i,j) < 2m$.)

*I should also note that in its original unedited version, the question did not state that $i$ and $j$ are adjacent, so while the earlier answers are relevant to the  original question, they are not relevant to the new edited version.*

If $i$ and $j$ are adjacent, the commute time $C(i,j)=h(i,j)+h(j,i)=2mR(i,j)$, where $R(i,j)$ is the effective resistance between $i$ and $j$ in G, and is at most $1$ (since $i$ and $j$ are connected by an edge). This shows that $h(i,j)<2m$ when $i$ and $j$ are adjacent in $G$, since both $h(i,j)$ and $h(j,i)$ are strictly positive.

The identity $C(i,j) = 2mR(i,j)$ holds for arbitrary vertices $i$ and $j$.  A proof appears, for example in the [book](http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/prbtree.html) by Lyons and Peres.

Comment: Thank you; if the result you stated holds also for bipartite graphs (I will check the reference you provided) then this does indeed answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

@user686 Sorry, for my earlier answer: I didn't realize you were concerned about $2m+1$ vs $2m$. However, in that case I don't think the claim made there is true if you add a self loop only at $j$. Random walks starting at $i$ in the case of both $G'$ and and $G$ can be coupled so that they take the $same$ steps at the same times until they reach $j$. This means that $H(i,j)_G=H(i,j)_{G'}$, and the expected hitting times therefore have to be equal.

Also, since the bound $h_{i,j} < 2m+1$ is not correct in general (on a path of $m$ nodes, $h_{i,j}$ can be as large as $\Theta(m^2)$), is your graph special?

PS: I updated my earlier answer since it seems it was not addressing your main concern.

Comment: On the other hand, if $i$ and $j$ are adjacent, the commute time $C(i,j) = h(i,j) + h(j,i) = 2mR(i,j)$, where $R(i,j)$ is the effective resistance between $i$ and $j$ in $G$, and is at most $1$.  This shows that $h(i,j) < 2m$ when $i$ and $j$ are adjacent in $G$, since both $h(i,j)$ and $h(j,i)$ are strictly positive.

Comment: It is fine (and sometimes better) to keep the answer even when it is incorrect or does not answer the question so others will not make the same mistake, just add a line to the start of the answer explaining why it is incorrect or does not answer the question. :)

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks, I am new here.  My earlier answer was not incorrect but didn't answer what user686 considered the important issue.

Comment: @Piyush: just add a line in bold to its top so it is clear that it is not answering the question.